# Why does Moon Reader not show up in 8 last apps list?

Tags: recents-screen, moon-reader

Normally, when you long-press on HOME button, my Android displays the icons for 8 last apps/activities that were active.

This seems to always be pretty reliable, with one exception.

For some reason, [Moon+ Reader app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreader&hl=en) that I ran today **does NOT appear on that list of 8 apps. At all.**

Is there any possible reason why?

*Environment*: Motorola Droid X, rooted stock Froyo 2.2 ROM, Zeam Launcher.

Comment: I'm using Moon+ on a Milestone² (aka Droid²) for a long time already, and quite regularly. Originally on the Froyo 2.2 ROM as well, meanwhile on CM7.2 (Gingerbread). Never saw the described behaviour. Moon+ always was in the "Recently used" list. You question looks like it only happened once to you. Did you have that issue frequently?

Comment: @Izzy - I haven't used Moon+ before, so I don't know; however it NEVER showed up in recently used list in the last 2 days; and I'm not aware of any other app that failed to show in the list ever, though I admit I don't diligently check every time I use every app :)

Comment: No accusation from my side -- I just wanted to share my experience of multiple years meanwhile. It's certainly not the apps fault either; but you might want to drop the dev a note. He's a very busy guy, but he won't ignore it. Just tell him I told you so :)

Comment: @Izzy - If it's not some setting explicitly done by the app, it's probably not worth bothering him :)  I'm hoping to rock newer hardware soon, will re-raise if the issue disappears

Comment: You might still watch if that happens to other apps as well, and maybe you find a pattern.